# open source C++ projects as an addon for Thunderbird

Tags: c++, email, xpcom, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

Could you will please tell me if there is open source C++ projects as an addon for Thunderbird? I need to develop one for e-mail processing. Any information on this subject is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: I'm pretty sure something this vague belongs at programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Enigmail](http://enigmail.mozdev.org/download/source.php.html) comes to mind. It has XPCOM components in C++.